# Why google play billing subscription instantly gets canceled?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription, play-billing-library, revenuecat

I have integrated the google play billing library inside my application to make a subscription purchase. It works well. The user receives purchase confirmation mail from google.
[confirmation mail from google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z1xr.jpg)

The active subscription is also visible in the play store subscriptions screen.
[Active subscription showing in play store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ttXW.jpg)

In the play console, the order detail said the user was successfully charged for a subscription. However, It gets canceled instantly.
[play console order history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAl4H.jpg)

I also check purchase acknowledgment, it returns true on every purchase. Initially, I thought there would be a mistake in my code. So, I tried various billing libraries from Github. The problem persists. In the end, I replaced the entire google billing library with Revenue cat. Followed every step described on Revenue cat documents. Still, getting the same issue.

Is there anything that I am missing to implement or done incorrectly? please help me out. Thank you

code for fetching available products:

```
 private fun fetchOffering(){
    Purchases.sharedInstance.getOfferingsWith({ error ->
        // An error occurred
        handleBillingError(requireActivity(), error)

    }) { offerings ->
        offerings.current?.availablePackages?.takeUnless { it.isNullOrEmpty() }?.let {
            // All packages from current offering

            if (it.isNotEmpty()){
                it.forEach { p: Package ->
                    offeringPackages.add(p)
                }
                isProductsAvailable = true
            }

            Log.d("RevenueCat", "fetchOffering: success: ${it.size}")

        }
    }
}
```

code for making purchase:

```
 private fun makePurchase(pack:Package){
    Purchases.sharedInstance.purchasePackageWith(
        requireActivity(),
        packageToPurchase = pack /* package from the fetched Offering*/,
        onError = {error, userCancelled ->
            Log.d("RevenueCat", "makePurchase: userCancelled: $userCancelled")
            handleBillingError(requireActivity(), error)
        },
        onSuccess = { product, purchaserInfo ->
            if (purchaserInfo.entitlements[REVENUE_ENTITLEMENT_ID_PRO]?.isActive == true) {
                Log.d("RevenueCat", "makePurchase: success: ${product.originalJson} ")
                afterPurchaseSuccessSetup()
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: can you share some Coding Files where you have work on subscription code?

Comment: @YahyaM I have edited question. You can check it out

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are lagging, you should follow these steps to make subscribe purchase.

```
private lateinit var billingClient: BillingClient
private val skuListsubscribe = listOf("subscription_1", "subscription_2")
```

initialize billing client.

```
 private fun setupBillingClient() {
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(BaseActivity.mContext!!)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .setListener(this)
        .build()
    billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
        override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.


                loadAllSKUsSubscription()

            }
        }

        override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
            Log.e("TAG", "onBillingServiceDisconnected: ")
        }
    })
}

private fun loadAllSKUsSubscription() = if (billingClient.isReady) {
    val params = SkuDetailsParams
        .newBuilder()
        .setSkusList(skuListsubscribe)
        .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
        .build()

    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params) { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->
        // Process the result.
        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList!!.isNotEmpty()) {
            for (skuDetails in skuDetailsList) {
                if (skuDetails.sku == subscribtionId) {

                    tv_full_category_price.text = skuDetails.price
                    realAmountSubscription = skuDetails.price

                    rl_bestvalue_plan.setOnClickListener {
                        isInAppPurchase = false
                        isSubscribtion = true
                        val billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams
                            .newBuilder()
                            .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                            .build()
                        billingClient.launchBillingFlow(requireActivity(), billingFlowParams)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


} else {
    println("Billing Client not ready")
}
```

**override purchase update method**

```
override fun onPurchasesUpdated(
    billingResult: BillingResult,
    purchases: MutableList<Purchase>?,
) {

   

    if (billingResult?.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
        for (purchase in purchases) {

            acknowledgePurchase(purchase)

        }
    } else if (billingResult?.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {


        //logger("User Cancelled")
        //logger(billingResult?.debugMessage.toString())

  
    } else {
        //logger(billingResult?.debugMessage.toString())

    }
}

 private fun acknowledgePurchase(purchase: Purchase) {

    if (isSubscribtion) {

        handleNonConsumableProduct(purchase = purchase)
    } 
}

fun handleConsumableProduct(purchase: Purchase) {

    val consumeParams =
        ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
            .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
            .build()

    billingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams) { billingResult, purchaseToken ->

        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {

            if (isVisible && isAdded)
                Snackbar.MakeInternetSnackbar(BaseActivity.mContext!!,
                    subscription_fragment_indicator_layout,
                    "Purchased Successfully")

            InAppPaymentApi(realAmount.toString(), audio_id!!, purchase.purchaseToken)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have tried every thing. same code as above and also tried implementing Github libraries. Still no luck. Same error